# Javascript post, withouth refreshing page

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following code, it is to post a message into the "chatbox", but when I put return false; at the end of the function, it will not submit the data, but when I remove it, it submits as it should be.

JS Code

```
function dopost() {
   var request;
    $("#chat").submit(function(event){
        if(request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        var $form = $(this);
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, button");
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "/chat.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });


        request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error("The following error occured:" + textStatus, errorThrown);
        });

        request.always(function(){
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    return false;
}
```

The Form

```
if(isset($_POST['chat'])) {
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
     $time = time();
     $userid = $user_class->id;
     $result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `newchat` (posted, posterid, message,extraid) VALUES ('" . $time . "', '0', '".$message."','" . $userid . "')") or die(mysql_error());

}
<form method='post' action='chat.php' id="chat">
            <div class='chatwrap'>
                <div class='chatlog'>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div style='width:600px;margin:0 auto;padding: 5px'>
                <input type='text' class='w400' name="message" value placeholder="Type message here..." /> <input type="submit" onclick="dopost();" name="chat"  />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Even when I add return false to the onclick it will not post, can anyone find the solution to this? It would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As it is, the `return` of `dopost` is not getting out of the event listener. To fix this with the style you're using just change

```
onclick="dopost();"
```

to

```
onclick="return dopost();"
```

Alternatively, you would need to add `dopost` as the listener directly, via an `addEventListener` or your preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a `dopost()` function anyway? Is very redundant. Using the listener is enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/L9Kfg/

On your html:

```
<input type="submit" name="chat" />
```

On your js:

```
   var request;
   $("#chat").submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       ...
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

as you're already using Jquery, I would sugest you have a look at $.post from Jquery, this uses what we call Ajax calls. In simple words, your webpage sends data using post, but stays on the same page, you can use the callback function to make an action once this post has been done.